# Timer IC that doesn't reset count because of power down and remembers last state

Tags: timer, memory, rtc

I'm looking for a timer/RTC that will count how long the system power was up in total and will toggle a pin after a specific time that will be configured in advance.
Does a timer that "remembers" exists?

For example, on the first time that the system is powered up for 2 hours, after this it's down, and powered up for 1 more hour, so in total the timer will be already 3 hours, etc.
After 500 hours (for example) I'd like to toggle a pin that will notify this.

The time resolution can be even hours, but I don't want to use a microcontroller (except for initial values configuration) or a battery (or supercap because I don't know for how long it will be down).

My main purpose is small size and less components, Power consumption is not an issue.

Thanks,

Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why no microcontroller/MCU? It is tiny, cheap and it can do what you want, because it has internal flash that can "store" the elapsed time. (An RTC component would need a battery or a supercap).

I would consider an MCU like the [ATtiny202](https://datasheet.octopart.com/ATTINY202-SSN-Microchip-datasheet-136609270.pdf).

Comment: The reason is that I prefer no code on the circuit, only for external initial configuration.

Comment: Your preference makes a simple problem with a simple solution hard to achieve.

Comment: I understand.Thank you.